# Troubleshooting XSLT compile error. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\_layouts\xsl\main.xsl'

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I am creating my own site template for SharePoint. Everything has been going fine, building fine, deploying fine. For unrelated reasons, I needed to reboot my development server. I then made an update to my custom.xsl file and attempted to deploy in Visual Studio 2012. Even though it says Deployed Successfully, My changes are not reflected in SharePoint, and I received the error in my question. Additionally, I am getting 32 warnings that this or that attribute is not declared, even though I made one small change (added a link for testing) to the blog.xsl I copied my custom .xsl from. I reverted all changes, attempted to deploy again, but cannot get past this error now.

Any ideas where to start looking to solve this? Needless to say _layouts is NOT in the root of the C drive, but it the 14 hive under Templates.